# Strange thing about simplification between product and productory

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Good morning,

I have this strange problem. I have to divide a product of 5 variables by 4 of the 5 variables : $C x_1 * x_2* x_3 *x_4 / (x_1 * x_2* x_3 *x_4)$. Now if I do this I don't obtain only $C$ but  $C x_3/x_3$. Also with `Refine` or `FullSimplify` doesn't change. **Now pay attention**: if I try with the code written in the way  you should read if I would paste it :

```
A = C*Product[Subscript[x, 
    i], {i, 1, 4}]/(Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[x, 3]*
     Subscript[x, 4])
```

I obtain

```
C
```

**I put a photo to summarize** (excuse me but my laptop has some problems with screenshot).

Why???? How we could do in the first method?

---

[image: code_photo]

Comment: go to the right of the expression `C x_3/x_3 ` and type  `// FullForm` . Most likely `x_3` in the numerator is not the same as `x_3` in the numerator but they look the same when typeset.

Comment: TIP: 1) don't use subscripts. 2) Don't use upper-case variables.

Comment: @kglr ok but it gives an expression    Times[C,Subscript[x,3],Power[Subscript[x,TextCell["3"]],-1]]  ( i have reported the expression because if i paste it add some other stuff). Now how can i have A= C ?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform i cant because i have to work with productory and many variables whose index is related to other things

Comment: there you have it: `Subscript[x,3]` is obviously not the same as `Subscript[x,TextCell["3"]]`

Comment: use `A /. TextCell[x_] :> ToExpression[x]` to get `C`.

Comment: @kglr yes, great thank you very much

Comment: siderius, you are welcome. I posted the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen capture of replicating the issue and solution:

[image]